# How to increase the accuracy of neural network model in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network, precision, apache-spark-mllib

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Load training data
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,"/home/.../neural.txt").toDF()

val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 1234L)
val train = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)

val layers = Array[Int](4, 5, 4, 4)
val trainer = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier().setLayers(layers).setBlockSize(128).setSeed(1234L).setMaxIter(100)
val model = trainer.fit(train)
// compute precision on the test set
val result = model.transform(test)
val predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label")
val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator().setMetricName("precision")
println("Precision:" + evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels))
```

I am using MultilayerPerceptronClassifier to build neural network in Spark. I am getting 62.5% of accuracy. What all parameters I should change to get good accuracy?

Comment: ... some code, what did you try so far, what are your settings?

Comment: I have edited post. Please check

Comment: This question is too broad: we don't know the data, we don't know what you are doing. Please write it again and enrich it with some details

Comment: I would advise you to follow some courses on neural networks to understand what parameter tuning means and how you should interpret the accuracy. If you need some help there, you'll need to define what is in your dataset, what you are looking to achieve, which ml algorithms you have used that lead you to having to use a neural net, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As some people has said , the question is too broad and cant be answered without more detail  but some advice(independently of the models/altorithms used or the tools and libraries for implementing them) would be:

- Use a cross validation set and perform some cross validation with different network architectures.
- Plot "Learning curves"
- Identify if you are having high bias or high variance
- See if you can or  need to apply feature scaling and/or normalization.
- Do some "Error Analysis"(manually verify which examples failed and evaluate or categorize them to see if you can find a pattern)

Not neccesarily in that order, but that could help you identify if you have underfitting, overfitting, if you need more training data, add or remove features, add regularization, etc. In summary , perform machine learning debugging.

Hope that helps, you can find more deep details about this in Andrew Ngs series of  videos, starting with this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIfLZAa32H0